# Create and use static library on OS X

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, static-libraries

OK, I'm trying to create a Cocoa Library (static) and use, but I keep getting errors.

I created a super-basic static Library (`TSXLib`) with just one additional class in it.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ClassOne : NSObject

- (void)doIt;

@end
```

---

```
#import "ClassOne.h"

@implementation ClassOne

- (void)doIt
{
    NSLog(@"Oops... I did it again!");
}

@end
```

Then, I set the **Dynamic Library Install Name** (in Build Settings) to :

```
@executable_path/../Frameworks/libTSXLib.a
```

Now in my Test Project :

- I drag'n'drop the `libTSXLib.a` file (and copied it to target)
- Added a Build Phase (Copy Files) where I'm copying the `libTSXLib.a` to `Frameworks`
- I'm then going to my `AppDelegate.m` and try importing my library's class
- At `#import <ClassOne.h>`, the compiler throws an error that it can't find the class

---

Any ideas?

---

**NOTE :** *I'm actually quite confused regarding libraries, frameworks, etc (that's why I tend to avoid them as much as possible). All I'm trying to do is pack some of classes/functions so that I can easily re-use them in different projects. Whether it is a framework, or a library, I really don't care. What I need is that : pack and re-use my code. (the ability to block anyone from seeing/using what's in, when bundled, would be a Plus)*

Comment: You don't copy static libraries you just link them - you are doing the correct thing if TSXLib was a dynamic library - I would make TSXLib asa dynamic library or Framework

Comment: @Mark If I stick to using a static library, how would I link it? Does it have to be bundled in the target app as well? And - last but not least - is there anything wrong with my header importing?

Comment: @Mark `Link Binary with Libraries` is set. `ClassOne.h` is set as public. But I still can't access it. Why's that?

Comment: @Mark The issue was resolved once I copied the header file, as well... :S

Comment: I would start with a tutorial - you are just moving things around to hope they work - you do need to understand them, as static libe=ries and headers should NOT be copied into the build  (unfortunately I can't find a Apple guide for static libraries for OSX just iOS which is different

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, so, coming back after some time, here's what I did to get it working :

### Step 1 : Create the Library

- Create a **New Project**, using the built-in Cocoa Library template
- Set **Library type** as *Static*.
- Add your Classes/Functions/Whatever
- Under **Build Phases**, take care of which headers are going to go *Public*.

### Step 2 : Use the Library in a test project

- *Drag’n'drop* the final .a library file into the project (doesn’t matter if you also copy it to the target directory)
- Link against the library
- Update the **User Header Search Paths** to your initial Library `.a` file origin (using recursion (like `/the/path/to/your/library/folder/**`)
- Set **Always search user paths** to `YES`
- Add `-ObjC` to **Other Linker Flags**, under **Build Settings**.